# Execute multiple policies

Tags: c#, .net, polly, retry-logic, policywrap

How to execute multiple policies (or combine them into a single one)?

For example I have:

```
var policy1 = Policy.Handle<DivideByZeroException>().WaitAndRetry(5));

var policy2 = Policy.Handle<StackOverflowException>().RetryForever();
```

How to apply them to one method at the same time?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As of Polly v5.0, there's a new [PolicyWrap](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap) class, which let you combine multiple policies.

```
var policy1 = Policy.Handle<DivideByZeroException>().WaitAndRetry(3, i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
var policy2 = Policy.Handle<StackOverflowException>().RetryForever();
PolicyWrap policyWrap = Policy.Wrap(policy1, policy2);
policyWrap.Execute(someGreatAction);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to combine two policies. Let me list all the different options for the sake of completeness. I will add recommendations for each: when to **use it** and when to *avoid it*

### Branch on exception

```
ExceptionDispatchInfo edi = null;
int retryCounter = 0;

var combinedPolicy = Policy
       .Handle<DivideByZeroException>()
       .Or<StackOverflowException>()
       .WaitAndRetry(CalculateSleep());

combinedPolicy.Execute(() => {
    try
    {
        //User code...
        throw new DivideByZeroException();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        edi = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);
        edi.Throw();
    }
});

IEnumerable<TimeSpan> CalculateSleep()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var wasItADivideByZero = edi.SourceException is DivideByZeroException;
        var attempt = retryCounter++;
        if (wasItADivideByZero)
        {
            if (attempt > 3) break;
            yield return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        }
        yield return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
    }
}
```

#### Notes

- The `WaitAndRetry` [does **not** have an overload](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/c27faf89ef459fd9a8e0131ae1d4cd835ca4f31d/src/Polly/Retry/RetrySyntax.cs) where you don't have to specify the `retryCount` but you can access the thrown exception inside the `sleepDurations`
- So, the built-in options support: either use `retryCount` + `sleepDurationProvider` (from where you can access the exception) or use `sleepDurations`
- That's why we have to [use `ExceptionDispatchInfo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64913559/c-rethrow-an-exception-from-a-variable-while-preserving-stack-trace/64913808#64913808) to capture the thrown exception and access it inside our custom `CalculateSleep` method

#### Use it

- If you would have two policies with the same amount of maximum retry attempts but with different sleep and different trigger, like this

```
var combinedPolicy = Policy
       .Handle<DivideByZeroException>()
       .Or<StackOverflowException>()
       .WaitAndRetry(3,
       (_, ex, __) => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ex is DivideByZeroException ? 1 : 2),
       (_, __, ___, ____) => { });
```

#### Avoid it

- Do not re-invent the wheel if you have other alternatives
- Even though the above solution works like a charm it is complex and hard to maintain

### Explicit continuation

```
policy1.Execute(() =>
{
    policy2.Execute(() =>
    {
        //User code
    });
});
```

OR

```
policy2.Execute(() =>
{
    policy1.Execute(() =>
    {
        //User code
    });
});
```

#### Notes

- The order does **not** matter here, because the two policies are independent

  - But please bear in mind that we have implemented here an [escalation chain](https://github.com/peter-csala/resilience-service-design/blob/main/resilience.md#esc)
- So, if we would have a retry and a timeout policy then the order would matter

  - Outer: Timeout; Inner: Retry >> Timeout is a *global, overarching*
  - Outer: Retry; Inner: Timeout >> Timeout is *local (so per attempt)*

#### Use it

- If you have no more than two policies and the to-be-decorated code is extracted into a separate method, like this

```
policy1.Execute(policy2.Execute(UserCode()));
```

#### Avoid it

- Welcome to the [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) / [Pyramid of doom](https://medium.com/dsc-srm/javascript-callback-hell-or-pyramid-of-doom-4f786d14b997)
- If you want to / need to separate policy definition from its execution

### The `Wrap` instance method

```
var combinedPolicy = policy1.Wrap(policy2);
combinedPolicy.Execute(UserCode());
```

OR

```
var combinedPolicy = policy2.Wrap(policy1);
combinedPolicy.Execute(UserCode());
```

#### Notes

- We could separate the policy definition from its execution
- The ordering does **not** matter here as well
- The `combinedPolicy`'s type is [`PolicyWrap`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/master/src/Polly/Wrap/PolicyWrap.cs), which implements the `ISyncPolicy` interface as well

#### Use it

- When you want to separate the policy definition from its usage
- It is suitable for combining no more than two policies

#### Avoid it

- If you want to combine more than 3 then it looks ugly IMHO

```
var combinedPolicy = globalTimeout.Wrap(retry).Wrap(circuitBreaker).Wrap(localTimeout);
```

- If you have a policy for a `void` and another policy for `TResult` then the system tries to act smart

  - The type of the `combinedPolicy` is now `PolicyWrap<string>`
- This combination is may or may not be intentional

  - If unintentional then it will **not** warn you about it

```
var policy1 = Policy.Handle<DivideByZeroException>().WaitAndRetry(3, i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
var policy2 = Policy<string>.Handle<StackOverflowException>().RetryForever();

var combinedPolicy = policy1.Wrap(policy2);
string? result = combinedPolicy.Execute(() => "dummy response");
```

### The `Wrap` static method

```
var combinedPolicy = Policy.Wrap(policy2, policy1);
```

OR

```
var combinedPolicy = Policy.Wrap(policy2, policy1);
```

#### Notes

- This static method can receive any number of `ISyncPolicy` or `ISyncPolicy<TResult>` policies

#### Use it

- With this method you could not combine a `ISyncPolicy` and a `ISyncPolicy<string>` policies because all policies should have the same type

```
var combinedPolicy = Policy.Wrap<HttpResponseMessage>(globalTimeout,retry,circuitBreaker,localTimeout);
```

#### Avoid it

- When you want to explicitly combine two or more policies where you have a `TResult` and one or more `void`

  - Or multiple `TResult` and one or more `void`
- Please note: You can **not** combine two policies where you have `TResult1` and `TResult2`